# Mongodb limit result number with something like groupby

Tags: mongodb, group-by, distinct, doctrine-odm

I have a MongoDB collection with multiple hierarchy, for the example I will use a collection with countries, that contain cities, each document is for a particular city and contain the population value for the country and the city (country_pop and city_pop in the example) this is very simplified, I have in reality 6 hierarchies and a big amount of data.

```
[
  {
    "country": "France",
    "city": "Paris",
    "country_pop": 63000000,
    "city_pop": 2200000,
    "year": 2015
  },
  {
    "country": "France",
    "city": "Marseille",
    "country_pop": 63000000,
    "city_pop": 850726,
    "year": 2015
  },
  {
    "country": "France",
    "city": "Toulouse",
    "country_pop": 63000000,
    "city_pop": 441802,
    "year": 2015
  },
  {
    "country": "France",
    "city": "Paris",
    "country_pop": 63500000,
    "city_pop": 2350000,
    "year": 2016
  },
  {
    "country": "France",
    "city": "Marseille",
    "country_pop": 63500000,
    "city_pop": 880726,
    "year": 2016
  },
  {
    "country": "France",
    "city": "Toulouse",
    "country_pop": 63500000,
    "city_pop": 445802,
    "year": 2016
  }
]
```

I am currently using doctrine mongo odm to Hydrate my documents into Php Object but it is not a requirement.
What I want to achieve is get in my php script values to display something like that :

- France :

  - 2015: 63000000
  - 2016: 63500000

Currently, I get **all** documents that match `{"country": "France"}` , so in this example I will get the 6 entries. But in reality, with a big amount of data, It's kinda bad to get 6 entries where I could get only two, one of year 2015 and one of year 2016 (because the value of country_pop will be the same in all entries that match `{"year": "2016", "country": "France"}`

During my test my php script use something like 100mo in order to generate a timeline of my values over the years and it is not acceptable. I agree that my documents structure is not very good but I have no control over it.

Is there any solution to do something like a 
select country_pop ... groupBy("country", "year") in order to get only the minimum results needed ?

I found the group query in doctrine mongodb odm documentation: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html#group-queries but there is no real explanations.

Also the mongo documentation for the "group"  method https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.group/ seems to be used to do some aggregation like sum or count and it is not what I am looking for.

Comment: You could maybe use distinct queries to achieve this somehow?

See here: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

May I ask why you are trying to avoid aggregation?  It seems like the perfect way to get what you are looking for with ease.

Comment: I dont want to avoid aggregation it just seems, by looking at the documentation, that it is used to group by country="france" and count how many documents I have like: {"france" : 6} and I need the value of my fields like "country_pop"… But maybe I'm wrong !
Edit: Maybe I can use the avg method, If it returns the average of my country_pop and there are all the same it might be the result I am looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for starters and let me know if you want any additional data:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    { 
        $group: { 
            "_id": { 
                "Country": "$country", 
                "Year": "$year", 
                "CountryPop": "$country_pop" 
            } 
        } 
    }
])
```

This will group your results by country, year, and country population and result in the following for your data set:

```
{ "_id" : { "Country" : "France", "Year" : 2016, "CountryPop" : 63500000 } }
{ "_id" : { "Country" : "France", "Year" : 2015, "CountryPop" : 63000000 } }
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! It is exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: You can do a lot of stuff with aggregation - don't be so quick to discount it!  Check out this tutorial with a zip code data set and look how easy it is to do things like - get the zip code with the highest population, get the population for a state, get the population of the USA, etc.  https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/aggregation-zip-code-data-set/